# How recover organization rights?

Tags: linkedin-api

Since the beginning of the month (March 2019), my Linkedin apps does not accept that I call the API services for organization (retrieve my organization, share icontent on the page of my organization).

So, I create a new application, I only have basic rights. How could I get rw_organization_admin, w_organization_social?

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply for access to [LinkedIn Marketing Developer Program](https://business.linkedin.com/marketing-solutions/marketing-partners/become-a-partner/marketing-developer-program).

From the [LinkedIn v1 to v2 API migration FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq):

> Looking to maintain access to rw_company_admin? Apply to the LinkedIn Marketing Developer Program to continue managing your Company Pages.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did it. Do you know how long it will take for linkedin to approve my application?

Comment: You should've received an email from LinkedIn stating that you will hear back within 30 business days. For me it's taking longer than 30 business days and I believe it's due to the large number of applications.

Comment: They should send a form to you via email pretty quick